# How to install a program in a 'system location'?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cmake

I am quite new to Linux in general, using Ubuntu 16.04. I am planning to install the ecCodes software (https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/ECC/ecCodes+installation), to load some grib files into R using the [gribr](https://github.com/nawendt/gribr) package. The installation instruction of the gribr package suggest that the ecCodes library should be best installed into a system location ("ecCodes installed in a system location: The the libraries/headers should be found by the linker/compiler without any additional environmental settings.")

In the installation instruction of ecCodes linked above, the corresponding line in the instructions says

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/where/you/install/eccodes ../eccodes-x.y.z-Source
```

So, to what path do I need to set `/path/to/where/you/install/eccodes` so that this is an appropriate system location?

Comment: It says the default is "/usr/local" so I would assume that would be their choice.

Comment: I don't know what "an appropriate system location" is for your program. Try /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin, which are usually default choices.

Comment: @mikewhatever from the default they show they probably want the location without ./bin/ and add it themself :-X

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the default... So /usr/local is a system directory that is automatically included in search paths, correct?

Answer (score -1):

The system location that you need to install it can vary. Your best bet would be to install it using a package manager like `apt-get`.

Check the ecCodes packages available [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eccodes). It appears that there is only source code available in the repos though.

Comment: so I cant just do `sudo apt-get install eccodes`, right?